# Search for available wireless networks

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I need to search for available wireless networks and take this list and store it. I tried searching in [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.aspx) for information, plus Google. But no luck.

Kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do regarding the wireless connection is determining the connection type. There is no way to access or manipulate details about the connection.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more information on using `NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType` to determine the connection type

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you want to do that there would be another way to accomplish your ultimate goal.

Comment: Does this mean there is no way to explicitly scan for available wireless networks on demand? For example, if you needed to scan more often than the system automatically does?

Comment: It is indeed not possible to force this. Network connections are handled by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone (even Mango) does not have an API that exposes this information.